# Can't read data on TensorFlow

Tags: python, tensorflow

Prior to this I converted my input images to TFRecords files. Now I have the following methods that I've mostly gathered from the tutorials and modified a little:

```
def read_and_decode(filename_queue):
    reader = tf.TFRecordReader()
    _, serialized_example = reader.read(filename_queue)
    features = tf.parse_single_example(
        serialized_example,
        # Defaults are not specified since both keys are required.
        features={
            'image/encoded': tf.FixedLenFeature([], tf.string),
            'image/class/label': tf.FixedLenFeature([], tf.int64),
        })
    image = tf.decode_raw(features['image/encoded'], tf.uint8)
    label = tf.cast(features['image/class/label'], tf.int32)

    reshaped_image = tf.reshape(image,[size[0], size[1], 3])
    reshaped_image = tf.image.resize_images(reshaped_image, size[0], size[1], method = 0)
    reshaped_image = tf.image.per_image_whitening(reshaped_image)
    return reshaped_image, label

def inputs(train, batch_size, num_epochs):
    filename = os.path.join(FLAGS.train_dir,
                          TRAIN_FILE if train else VALIDATION_FILE)

    filename_queue = tf.train.string_input_producer(
        [filename], num_epochs=num_epochs)

    # Even when reading in multiple threads, share the filename
    # queue.
    image, label = read_and_decode(filename_queue)

    # Shuffle the examples and collect them into batch_size batches.
    # (Internally uses a RandomShuffleQueue.)
    # We run this in two threads to avoid being a bottleneck.
    images, sparse_labels = tf.train.shuffle_batch(
        [image, label], batch_size=batch_size, num_threads=2,
        capacity=1000 + 3 * batch_size,
        # Ensures a minimum amount of shuffling of examples.
        min_after_dequeue=1000)
    return images, sparse_labels
```

But when I try to call a batch on iPython/Jupyter, the process never ends (there appears to be a loop). I call it this way:

```
batch_x, batch_y = inputs(True, 100,1)
print batch_x.eval()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you are missing a call to [`tf.train.start_queue_runners()`](https://www.tensorflow.org/versions/r0.10/api_docs/python/train.html#start_queue_runners), which starts the background threads that drive the input pipeline (e.g. some of these are the threads implied by `num_threads=2` in the call to `tf.train.shuffle_batch()`, and the [`tf.train.string_input_producer()`](https://www.tensorflow.org/versions/r0.10/api_docs/python/io_ops.html#string_input_producer) also requires a background thread). The following small change should unblock things:

```
batch_x, batch_y = inputs(True, 100,1)
tf.initialize_all_variables.run()    # Initializes variables.
tf.initialize_local_variables.run()  # Needed after TF version 0.10.
tf.train.start_queue_runners()       # Starts the necessary background threads.
print batch_x.eval()
```

Comment: Thank you, now I get the following warning: ERROR:tensorflow:Exception in QueueRunner: Attempting to use uninitialized value input_producer/limit_epochs/epochs
  [[Node: input_producer/limit_epochs/CountUpTo = CountUpTo[T=DT_INT64, _class=["loc:@input_producer/limit_epochs/epochs"], limit=1000, _device="/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/cpu:0"](input_producer/limit_epochs/epochs)]]. Do you know what could be causing it?

Comment: I updated the question with the other piece of missing boilerplate. You need to call `tf.initialize_all_variables.run()` (or `sess.run(tf.initialize_all_variables())`). If that doesn't work (depending on the version) you might also need to add `tf.initialize_local_variables().run()` as well.